# Kendo UI for Angular kendo-combobox displays the popup wrong when the page is scrolled in Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, scroll, bootstrap-4, kendo-combobox

I'm using the current version of the kendo-combobox (@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns@1.2.1). It is used in a bootstrap theme and I'm using bootstrap 4 (@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5).
I have not added any CSS aside from color changes.
When I'm using the combobox in Firefox 55.0.3 (64-Bit) the popup part of the combobox will stay fixed, when the windows scrolls. So when I scroll down the box moves up. If I open a combobox which is already way down the popup will not show up, because it is all the way up. I can scroll up to up then, so it is loaded.

This problem has occured several times if you google for it, but the solution from 2012 does not seem to do it for me.

I've tried to add the class:

```
.k-ff {
  overflow: inherit !important;
}
```

But I'm not entirely shure how. I've added it to my css file and added it to the body tag and to the div containing my combo-box (not at the same time), but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to the following issue that is already addressed, and you can expect a fix released soon:

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/900)